# Does providing university email benefit resume?

Tags: professionalism, resume, job-search, email

I am in the final year of my degree and starting to look for jobs. I have a university mail and a general all-purpose mail. Does it matter which one I provide in my resume? Will providing the education mail help in some sense?

Comment: Some unis (ie. University of Bristol) provide emails for life. Will your email address expire after you leave the institution? This is a big consideration.

Comment: Depends on the university. If it ends in mit.edu or harvard.edu, it may have some benefit. Otherwise it probably does more harm. One of my sons still uses his MIT address and is doing fine with it.

Comment: and you never know.... My alma mater has changed my 'lifetime' e-mail address twice since I graduated, and it is by no means a little known, inexpensive, or fly by night institution.

Answer (score 9):

No, it does not matter. If the company is interested in your education background, they will ask for transcripts, certificates etc. Putting the name of your university and your major on your resume definitely helps.

One thing to note is how long you can keep your university email account. At some places it is terminated after you graduate. This is not what you'd want as the hiring process may extend beyond that.

You may also consider setting up another email account if you'd like to separate personal and work matters.

Comment: Also it's important that your general purpose email is professional sounding such as "<your first name>_<your surname>@gmail.com" and not "ImmaTool@gmail.com". I've definitely gotten resumes with the latter. I just chuckle and toss them.

Comment: @jcmack What if the applicant is otherwise perfect for the job? Let's say he graduated from a well known university, has ~10 years of valuable experience, open source contributor etc., but the email address is _destroyerOfTheWorlds3@example.org_. Would you still toss it?

Comment: @s.alem Yup. I would still toss it, because the candidate seems immature and lacks professionalism. Having the hard skills is just part of what hiring managers look at.

Comment: Professional sounding is in the eye of the beholder.  I know folk who will toss anything that isn't strictly firstname_lastname@mailserver.com, and those who look at the mail server as well for evidence of professionalism.  Resumes have been tossed for being address@yahoo.com or address@aol.com even if the address was professional.  I know someone personally who is a Freemason, and his address is OnTheSquare[a number of his choosing]@hisemailserver.com, and his resume's been tossed a couple of times because of that.

Comment: @s.alem A posting easily generates 50 resumes from people who went to well known universities and claim to have whatever experience the job calls for.  Management wants deciding which 5 to interview to be an under two hour task.  Gotta pare it down some how, don't leave 'gimmes' in there to put you in the wrong pile.

Answer (score 2):

Time is the biggest factor. If that resume/CV ends up in a place where it could be used to contact you after you lose access to the university email account, then the resume loses its effectiveness if that is the only contact information given.

For students looking for internships the university email system is a good way to be contacted. Many universities have job boards that employers can interact with therefore a university email address helps with that process.

For students about to graduate having an email address not linked to the university helps you keep those job search messages separate from the blizzard of emails that the university is sending you during those frantic last weeks of your last semester.

Answer (score 2):

This is right out of a class that I used to teach.

No, your email domain is not a factor.  What matters is your email name.

It should be professional and simple.

I maintain a professional email and a private one, and I recommend the same for everyone.  Also, don't use a domain that you may not be using over the years if you change carrier or membership, such as in a university or business.

Your professional email should be in a format that makes sense and has nothing controversial.

**GOOD EXAMPLES**

> John.Doe@gmail.com
>
> JDoe@gmail.com
>
> Doe.John@gmail.com

or something like that.  That way, the recruiter, hiring manager, et cetera knows who you are without even opening your email.  It makes you stand out as a professional.

**WHAT TO AVOID**

Anything that indicates political affiliation, sports teams, or anything that is lewd or suggestive...

**BAD EXAMPLES**

> YankeesFan@gmail.com

yes, this could annoy someone and get you bumped.

> IVoteDemocrat@gmail.com

This is not going to endear you to anyone of a differing party.  Ditto for any political party.

> HighHeels@gmail.com

Not professional, could be taken as suggestive.

> NartutoFan@gmail.com

Again, unprofessional.

**TLDR:**

1. Pick an email specifically to put on your resume.
2. Use a combination of your firstname and lastname if possible
3. Keep it professional
4. Do not reference politics, sports, anything suggestive or anything silly.
5. The domain does not matter.
6. Use an email address that is not going to change.

Comment: Popular email providers tend to have all the common combinations taken already. So if you want a professional name try using your own web server so you can create a professional combination without worry, ex JohnDoe@yourdomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that

1. Your address **will not expire** after you leave the Uni, either by dropping out or by graduating. For example University of Bristol provide email accounts for life, via Gmail.
2. The address contains your name and surname, like a normal email should. My UoB account, for example, was my initials followed by a number, which is not great for readability.

Initially I used my uni address because I thought it adds prestige, but I didn't notice any difference by switching to my normal `name.surname@provider.su` account, except that it made it slightly easier to remember only one address.

Comment: Provider.su - where SU is the TLD for the former USSR - has the potential to be taken as a polical statement which may not be desired for a job application. In this case I think something else may be more appropriate...?

Comment: @Jakg Нет, товарищ

Answer (score 0):

Use your general purpose email address.

The application processes might drag on until after you graduated. When your university time is over, you might no longer be able to access your university email address, so you might miss crucial communication with your prospective employers.